# latest Zeppelin snapshot version 0.8.snapshot is broken on helium

Tags: apache-zeppelin

The latest snapshot version of Zeppelin which was checked out few minutes back is broken on helium. Even after enabling helium packages, it is not available as option on the visualization bar.

Comment: This issue is fixed now. But there is still one more issue, Spark Tutorial shows a blank screen after opening.

Comment: Hi, Zeppelin community fixed that issue few days ago

- https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2421

Comment: Spark tutorial is fixed too. https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2432